# using flutter arcore with camera plugin at the same time

Tags: flutter, arcore

I want to use the camera plugin for my object detection model and the arcore to amerce the 3d object if it was detected by the model but it seems that the arcore is monopolizing camera resources is there a way to go around it .

Comment: Hey, I'm also stuck in a similar situation. Have you managed to do this?

Comment: i  added this [pr](https://github.com/giandifra/arcore_flutter_plugin/pull/141) manually to the cached plugin to take screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data from the camera(CameraImage) and send it to a new isolate as a message where you can use your model to perform inference(prediction) for you.